# How do I return a value inside the loop so that other methods can access it?

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, return, do-while

Basically, I need to return the correct year, which is above 2022. I need to return it so that other methods can access it. This is suppose to be a loop saying error if the user doesn't type it.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean good = false;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the expiration year:");
            int userYear = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            if(userYear > 2022)
              good = true;
            else 
              System.out.println("Invalid. Try again.");
            int userYears = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
        }
        while (!good);
        good = false;

       // return userYear;
```

I want to return here so that my other methods can see.

Answer (score 0):

Create int userYears outside of the loop. And then simply change the value inside the loop. You don't need both userYears and userYear. They are variables and their value can be changed

Comment: I'm confused how that would help because even if I change the variables, it's not going to allow me to return the input value I need so other methods can access it.

Comment: You will just have to pass that value into the method that you need. Or you can create a public instance variable

Answer (score 0):

You can return it immediately

```
if (userYear > 2022) {
    return userYear;
}
```

or, if you need to do some stuff before returning the value, create variable `userYear` outside (before) the loop

```
int userYear;
do {
    // some code
} while (!good);
// some more code
return userYear;
```